# Pandas df.sum() creating only 0s

Tags: python, pandas

I have a large `df` of information that I want to add a 'Total' column to. However, when I use the `sum()` method the resulting column is populated only with 0 values.

Here is a slice of my `df`:

```
    COL NAME0  COL NAME1  COL NAME2  COL NAME3  COL NAME4
0     Alabama   4.099099   4.090001   2.042345   NaN
1      Alaska   1.396396   1.390001   1.000000   1.000000
2     Arizona   4.189189   NaN        2.003257   1.537777
3    Arkansas   2.927928   2.920001   2.208723   NaN
4  California   3.378378   3.780001   1.754930   2.012395
```

To add the `Total` column, I did the following:

```py
df['Total'] = df.sum(axis=1)
```

which created the following `df`:

```
    COL NAME0  COL NAME1  COL NAME2  COL NAME3  COL NAME4  Total
0     Alabama   4.099099   4.090001   2.042345   NaN        0.0
1      Alaska   1.396396   1.390001   1.000000   1.000000   0.0
2     Arizona   4.189189   NaN        2.003257   1.537777   0.0
3    Arkansas   2.927928   2.920001   2.208723   NaN        0.0
4  California   3.378378   3.780001   1.754930   2.012395   0.0
```

I then tried a different approach, to add each column to the `Total` column one at a time:

```py
for col in df:
    df['Total'] = df['Total'] + df[col]
```

However, this results in the `Total` column being populated with only `NaN` values.

My guess is the existing `NaN` values in `df` is causing this behavior in the `Total` column. This seems to be a simple task so if there's something I'm overlooking let me know. Any suggestions/ solution would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suggest filter out first column with strings and convert all another columns to floats:

```
df['Total'] = df.iloc[:, 1:].astype(float).sum(axis=1)
```

---

```
print (df.dtypes)
COL NAME0    object
COL NAME1    object
COL NAME2    object
COL NAME3    object
COL NAME4    object
dtype: object

df['Total'] = df.sum(axis=1)
print (df)
    COL NAME0 COL NAME1 COL NAME2 COL NAME3 COL NAME4  Total
0     Alabama  4.099099  4.090001  2.042345       NaN    0.0
1      Alaska  1.396396  1.390001  1.000000  1.000000    0.0
2     Arizona  4.189189       NaN  2.003257  1.537777    0.0
3    Arkansas  2.927928  2.920001  2.208723       NaN    0.0
4  California  3.378378  3.780001  1.754930  2.012395    0.0

df['Total'] = df.iloc[:, 1:].astype(float).sum(axis=1)
print (df)
    COL NAME0 COL NAME1 COL NAME2 COL NAME3 COL NAME4      Total
0     Alabama  4.099099  4.090001  2.042345       NaN  10.231445
1      Alaska  1.396396  1.390001  1.000000  1.000000   4.786397
2     Arizona  4.189189       NaN  2.003257  1.537777   7.730223
3    Arkansas  2.927928  2.920001  2.208723       NaN   8.056652
4  California  3.378378  3.780001  1.754930  2.012395  10.925704
```

If need processing columns later:

```
df =  df.astype(dict.fromkeys(df.columns[1:], 'float'))
print (df.dtypes)
COL NAME0     object
COL NAME1    float64
COL NAME2    float64
COL NAME3    float64
COL NAME4    float64
dtype: object


df['Total'] = df.sum(axis=1)
print (df)
    COL NAME0  COL NAME1  COL NAME2  COL NAME3  COL NAME4      Total
0     Alabama   4.099099   4.090001   2.042345        NaN  10.231445
1      Alaska   1.396396   1.390001   1.000000   1.000000   4.786397
2     Arizona   4.189189        NaN   2.003257   1.537777   7.730223
3    Arkansas   2.927928   2.920001   2.208723        NaN   8.056652
4  California   3.378378   3.780001   1.754930   2.012395  10.925704
```

Answer (score 2):

you could also select the columns by dtypes :

```
df['Total'] = df.select_dtypes(exclude=['object']).sum(axis=1)


print(df)

    COL_NAME0   COL_NAME1   COL_NAME2   COL_NAME3   COL_NAME4   Total
0   Alabama     4.099099    4.090001    2.042345    NaN         10.231445
1   Alaska      1.396396    1.390001    1.000000    1.000000    4.786397
2   Arizona     4.189189    NaN         2.003257    1.537777    7.730223
3   Arkansas    2.927928    2.920001    2.208723    NaN         8.056652
4   California  3.378378    3.780001    1.754930    2.012395    10.925704
```

Comment: I thinking about this solution too, but here working nice OP solution.

Comment: I like yours but I think his data frame might have more columns so this works a little better I think (: (also it might have bools and category datatype so mine may error too)

Comment: No, I think sometjing else, `df['Total'] = df.select_dtypes(exclude=['object']).sum(axis=1)` and `df['Total'] = df.sum(axis=1)` working with sample data same way.

Comment: oh, you are right, strange he must have a different df to the sample one then. we will have to wait for OP to see if either work